# Error in Shipping Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, shipping-methods

I am facing error `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time`.I am using Webshopapps Matrix extension for shipping and import the shipping charges through csv(see below image of csv).For simple i have weights like (`5000`,`0.5000`).Can someone tell me why i got this error.Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: We assume you are shipping to GBR?

Comment: these are country names.

Comment: I know. You don't mention this in the question, so when you are shipping to germany, there is no quote for shipping...

Comment: Mean it will only work for country that are in csv right ? but i want to shipp to U.K and that are in csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons. Firstly, there is no value for the "Delivery Type", so you need to fill this out, i.e. "Standard Delivery", "Next Day Delivery" or whatever.

Could you then also tell us about the product. What is it's weight? From memory, if the weight is 0, it will be ignored.

If you have more than one store, you will need to upload the csv to each store too.

Comment: Also, you have gaps in your weights.  What happens if the combined weight is 100.5?  Your FROM should be the last one's TO.

Comment: Yep Douglas is correct with that. So on 1 line is 0-100, line 2 should be 100-200. Admittedly, the example that is shown on WSA doesn't show this, but it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: i have multiple products in cart like simple and configurable.The weight of simple on is `500.0000` and configurable have no weights.So that might be issue ?

Comment: I have one store with multiple languages.

Comment: i have weights like 0.5000 or 500.0000.what i will do to remove the error ?

Comment: Hi Mahmood. Do you get the problem when you only add one product to the cart?

Comment: i got this issue sometime on shipping method.

Comment: So you mean that it only happens occasionally?

Comment: yes i think on some products it shows me the error.i try to remove one config product from cart and the error gone.

Comment: Drop us a mail at WebShopApps and we will take a look. There are no known issues with the extn, but it is unsupported. FYI on the to/from fields with the free version it is >= and <= so you need to increment slighty e.g. 0-100, 100.01-200, not as James has indicated. On most of the paid extensions is > and <=